# Laravel nova redirect 404 when use .htaccess default to public folder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm use .htaccess file in root directory and setting to redirect public folder, It's work but when use laravel nova and set nova config path to "/admin" after login nova will be redirect to "https://example.com/public/admin" screen will show this message

"404 Whoops… We're lost in space. The page you were trying to view does not exist."

when click go home button nova will be redirect to "https://example.com/admin" and work.

how to config nova with .htaccess when first login?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4LPu.png)

Comment: Can you provide the contents of your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: You need to point your domain to the `/public` directory, a redirect is not enough.

Comment: @FrancinaldoAlmeida I'm use `RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]` or what is you mean?

Comment: @Sven I have a question in my cpanel go to domain > redirect right? If true it's same in my .htaccess file, I don't know about nova redirect because nova has public owner.

Comment: I am not sure how to accomplish this using CPanel